# Is there a word describing a parent who does not recognize their child as adult?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider a parent who has a grown-up and independent offspring. However, they refuse to respect and recognize the independence of the child and do not really consider them as adult. I know it is possible to say :

> The parent does not see their child as an adult.

However I was wondering if there is a single verb or any other type of word that describes the parent or his action in this situation?

Comment: You could say that the parent *infantilizes* their adult child.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Seems to be close to what I am looking for. Although infant means a young child and I guess infantilization might hint a little at treating someone as if they are a young child. However the meaning I am looking for is not being recognized as an independent equal adult and not necessarily being treated as a young child. Why don’t you add your response as an answer so we can discuss it further under that?